# stripe checkout not not working like in the demo

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripes

Hi i'm trying to insert Stripe on my php website, i took the Stripe sample from the their website but all i receive instead of a nice checkout page is nothing more than text, i'm in local using Wamp, stripe php is install through composer`the create-checkout-session.php` [the server part]  `

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51GnYWKFeoY7b2LtguaCMHEyazW1Ly9SsOhpig3V27QwSURm8xTXZQIe7toFA39v5A34CIzBrZL7o0Y5lYJkiVToC00V1gsNvwi');

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'unit_amount' => 2000,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);

echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);``
```

the checkout.html [the front part]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Buy cool new product</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="product">
        <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
          alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
        />
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
          <h5>$20.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
    </section>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51GnYWKFeoY7b2LtgWEqcinzq7f7xCsQA8RPvCcWDvF5YIl3573ueUJKBlQEMo8P5nIM3vu1dj6YmRD3auTmDaw0K00njLvdBQ1");
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("/create-checkout-session.php", {
        method: "POST",
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
          // error, you should display the localized error message to your
          // customer using error.message.
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Here what i receive when i go on localhost 4242

```
{"id":"cs_test_a1jEBgtlzTJrv4MMwTCgsKgHrCLM0k31Ztrk620EV2H8StQApoptTudXrZ"}
```

Comment: Looks like maybe you went directly to create-checkout-session.php and received the JSON in the browser window.

Comment: Why are you expecting to see a checkout page? The PHP script is working as intended, it echoes some JSON.  What do you think it should be doing?

Comment: Go to checkout.html instead

Comment: Thanks for your answers i wanted to make the stripe example work for integrating it to my website, in the demo they click on checkout and go to the stripe page with the item on the left and on the right what's necessary for the payment

Comment: Ok. What's your point? Did you understand our answers? Did you check the things we suggested?

Comment: Yes thank you the sample is now working even on my project, my problem now is that i integrated the script to my cart page which is in php and change the domain url for it, unfortinately it's not working again (maybe because of my php code)

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. You'll need to be more specific about the issue

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `localhost:4242` is pointing to your `create-checkout-session.php` file, which is returning a Checkout Session ID as json as expected.

You need to make sure that `localhost:4242` points to your `checkout.html` file instead. Look into your server set up to see if you can find out why it's pointing to the wrong file.

As a side note, you left your secret test API key in the question. That key is now compromised, you should roll it immediately at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

Comment: thank you for the answer i roll my key and check my 4242